# Get ID from PHP URL and use in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I've put certain values like a user id into the url e.g /index.php?id=1 in previous PHP files.

I have a HTML form that has an action like this:

```
    <form name="staffResponse" method="post" action="respond_ticket.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Which when you go to respond_ticket.php and simply echo the value for the id and look at the URL it does it successfully. Whats more the data that I am posting to that file is also done without problem. However I want to then write that information to a table but it does not seem to work.

Here is the respond_ticket.php file

```
<?php
include 'database/db.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$staffResponse = $_POST['staffResponse'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (staffResponse) VALUES ('$staffResponse') WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if ($result === TRUE) {
echo '<p>Response ' . $staffResponse . ', has been added</p>';
}
else {
echo '<p class="warning">Unable to respond</p>';
}

?>
```

The db.php file has all the necessary information for connection to the database i.e name password etc. It also opens the question there too.

I keep just getting the warning message that I wrote.

Comment: `INSERT INTO` cannot have a where clausel

Comment: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - 2nd one today. Next time, RTFM.

Comment: `else {
echo '<p class="warning">Unable to respond</p>';
}` does NOT help you. This will http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: should check if `$id` exists (or not)

Comment: Do you trust your staff not to spoof that id?

Comment: You should escape that id.

Answer (score 3):

you cant do an insert with a where modifier like this. change it to update ;)

```
 UPDATE tickets SET staffResponse = '$staffResponse' WHERE id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use a `WHERE` clause with `INSERT`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets (staffResponse) VALUES ('$staffResponse')";
```

You may wish to set your tickets table up with auto increment so you dont need to insert an id if you haven't done that already.

Answer (score 0):

use ON DUPLICATE UPDATE if it helps

```
INSERT INTO tickets (id,staffResponse) VALUES ('$id','$staffResponse')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), staffResponse=VALUES(staffResponse)
```